# Envelop signature with mandatory ICP

Tags: json, api, docusignapi, signature, scp

I am transmitting an envelope for signature in the API and I need the use of the electronic signature Brazil(ICP) to be mandatory. I use the json below and even so Docusing is allowing signing without a certificate.

Some help?

I need the signature to be done only using the digital certificate

`

```
"recipientSignatureProviders": [
                    {
                        "signatureProviderName": "universalsignaturepen_icp_smartcard_tsp",
                        "signatureProviderOptions": {
                            "cpfNumber": "9999999999",
                            "signerRole": "Responsavel Assinatura Digital"
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

`

Comment: Can you do it via the web app manually? not using the API?

Comment: I'm using API/envelope and the above json example

Comment: yes, but the reason I'm asking is to understand if the issue is in the API or in the account configuration.

Comment: If you are able to do it via web app - it will mean the issue is with the API

Comment: If you cannot do it via the web app either - it means that your account is not configured correctly

Comment: I will check with the person responsible for the account, let me know the result, thanks for the information

Comment: we found out that the company account on docusign does not have this service

thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Digital Signature or [Standard Based Signature](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/standards-based-signatures/) does not exist in most accounts, you have to work with either DocuSign Customer Support or your Account Manager to enable this feature for your account and then you can use it.